# Cmake Error when building glew 2.0.0 with MinGW 4.9.2

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, mingw, glew

I want to build the GLEW 2.0.0 library with MinGW 4.9.2. (w64 version) and CMake 3.7.2 on a win10 64 bit machine.
The configuration step works fine, but the generation step fails with an error I do not fully understand.

```
CMake Error:
    Error evaluating generator expression:

    $<TARGET_PDB_FILE:glew>

    TARGET_PDB_FILE is not supported by the target linker.
```

Why is a pdb-file generated which is incompatible to the linker?

I previously built the glfw 3.2.1 library without problems, therefore I assume that my combination of tools is unlikely to be totally incompatible. Both libraries use the same MinGW version and therefore identical make/gcc/ld executables.
I searched for this error on the web but was unable to find any information on this.

Edit: I selected MinGW Makefiles as generator for both projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help: https://github.com/nigels-com/glew/issues/138.

I was trying to build glew in a similar setup and got the same error.  Following the link I added a correction to line 194 of CMakeLists.txt:

```
if(WIN32 AND (NOT MSVC_VERSION LESS 1600) AND (NOT CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS "3.1"))
```

changed to

```
if(WIN32 AND MSVC AND (NOT MSVC_VERSION LESS 1600) AND (NOT CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS "3.1"))
```

which allowed CMake to finish.

I gather this might be something to do with whether you use VisualStudio on Windows.